# How to save custom field value in sales_order table before place order in magento2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order

I have use event `checkout_submit_all_after` and `sales_order` table field `test_field`.

```
class SalesOrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order->setTestField(12);
            $order->save();   
        }
    }
```

TestField in not save value.how does it save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Find answer Use `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` event..

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order->setTestField(10);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But i need to update value in sales_order_grid table

Comment: do we have to create field to store value? or it will create when its run first time?

Comment: Need to create a field in quote and order table then etc.xml in define copy field value

Answer (score 0):

Try following way

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order->setTestField(177);
            $order->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

[Update]

**Vendor/Modue/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="custom_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="Vendor\Modue\Observer\SalesOrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: I have already check with it..but not working..any another way? @ sohel

Comment: It's working fine here. Did you clear cache?

Comment: yes.. but it's not working yet.

Comment: Can you post your event.xml? Something wrong here may be.

Comment: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="btn_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="Test\Demo\Observer\SalesOrderPlaceAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>

Comment: Check updated answer and make sure your module is enable.

Comment: yes, module is enabled. check it with generating a log. you mean observer name effect that's things? or not define xml?

Comment: and I try it above code..but not luck..may be other events use? any idea?

Comment: Which magento version you tried? It's working fine 2.1.x.

Comment: 2.1.6..why does not work in my Magento?

Comment: An observer is working fine I check it with creating a log in observer but not save my custom field value.

Comment: Try updated answer and check it gives any error or not. Working fine in default setup.

Comment: thanx, i will it now.

Comment: No any log generate just debug.log is create.[2017-06-11 10:33:08] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://127.0.0.1/magneto215/rest/it/V1/carts/mine/payment-information","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_2","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

Comment: [2017-06-11 10:29:40] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://127.0.0.1/magneto215/checkout/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

Comment: anything finds out solutions about it?